# How to create a columns based on other columns SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have 2 tables `@Claims` and `@ClaimsActivity`:

[image]

Query:

```
declare @Claims table (ClaimID int)

insert into @Claims 
values (6070), (6080)

declare @ClaimsActivity table 
                        (
                            Activityid int, 
                            ClaimID int, 
                            Activity int, 
                            ActivityDate datetime, 
                            ClaimStatus int
                        )

insert into @ClaimsActivity 
values (1, 6070, 0, '2017-11-05 20:23:16.640', 0),
       (3, 6070, 6, '2017-11-06 13:50:28.203', 0),
       (4, 6070, 9, '2017-11-07 13:39:28.410', 0),
       (5, 6070, 10, '2017-11-07 13:40:49.980', 0),
       (7, 6070, 8, '2017-11-07 15:46:18.367', 1),
       (8, 6070, 8, '2017-11-07 16:50:49.543', 1),
       (9, 6070, 9, '2017-11-07 16:50:54.733', 0),
       (10, 6070, 4, '2017-11-07 16:55:22.135', 0),
       (11, 6070, 6, '2017-11-08 18:32:15.101', 0),
       (12, 6080, 0, '2017-11-12 11:15:17.199', 0),
       (13, 6080, 8, '2017-11-13 09:12:23.203', 1)

select * 
from @Claims

select * 
from @ClaimsActivity 
order by ActivityDate
```

I need to add 2 columns based on data in `@ClaimsActivity`: `IsReopened`  and   `DateReopened`

The logic is:

- If the last `ClaimStatus` (based on ActivityDate) = 1 then `IsReopened` = 0
- But if the last `ClaimStatus` = 0 then it need to go and check whether one of the `Activity` is = `9` (Claim Reopened)
- and if one of the Activity = 9 then `IsReopened` should = 1 and `DateReopened` should be the last date when it was reopened

I brought column `StatusOfClaim`, but I also need `IsReopened`  and   `DateReopened`

```
select 
    Claimid,
    isnull((select top 1 
                case when al.ClaimStatus = 1 
                   then 'Closed' 
                   else 'Open' 
                end
            from
                @ClaimsActivity al 
            where 
                C.ClaimID = al.ClaimID 
            order by  
                al.ActivityDate desc), 'Open') as 'Status of Claim',
    NULL as 'isReopen',
    NULL as 'DateReopened'
from
    @Claims c
```

Desired output should be like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many different ways you can accomplish this, but here is an example using `CROSS APPLY` and `OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT 
    ClaimID,
    CASE WHEN tmp.IsOpen = 1 THEN 'Open' ELSE 'Closed' END AS 'Status of Claim',
    CASE WHEN tmp.IsOpen = 1 AND lastReopen.Activityid IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'isReopen',
    lastReopen.ActivityDate AS 'DateReopened'
FROM @Claims c
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT ISNULL((
            SELECT TOP 1 CASE WHEN al.ClaimStatus = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
            FROM @ClaimsActivity al 
            WHERE c.ClaimID = al.ClaimID 
            ORDER BY al.ActivityDate DESC
        ), 1) AS IsOpen
    ) tmp
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1
            al.Activityid,
            al.ActivityDate
        FROM @ClaimsActivity al 
        WHERE c.ClaimID = al.ClaimID AND al.Activity = 9
        ORDER BY al.ActivityDate DESC 
    ) lastReopen
```

The `CROSS APPLY` is just used to produce a column that tells us whether a claim is open or closed, and we can reuse this throughout the rest of the query.

The `OUTER APPLY` is used to grab to the last "reopen" activity for each claim, of which you want the date.

I can't attest to the performance of this query, but this should at least give you the correct results.